# List resets / doesn't insert the values

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, map

I have the following code:

```
public class usersManagement 
{
  public Map<String,User__c> usersMap;
  public List<User__c> selectedUsers;
  public String retrievedUsers {get;set;} 
  public String userToRemove {get;set;}

  public usersManagement(){
    usersMap = new Map<String,User__c>();
    selectedUsers = new List<User__c>();
  }

  public void getUsers(){
    ABxUserController usersList = new ABxUserController();
    users = usersList.getAllUsers();
    fillUsersMap(users);
  }

  public void fillUsersMap(List<User__c> userList){        
    userList.sort();
    if(!usersMap.isEmpty())
    usersMap.clear();
    for(User__c user : userList){
      usersMap.put(user.User_Name__c,user);
    }
  }

  public void setSelectedUsers(){
    User__c currentUser;

    List<String> profileUsers = removeQuotes(retrievedUsers).split(',');      

    for(String profileUser : profileUsers){
      currentUser = new User__c();
      if(profileUser != null && profileUser.length() > 0){ 
        if(usersMap.get(profileUser) != null){                    
          currentUser = usersMap.get(profileUser);
          System.debug('current user: ' + currentUser);
          if(currentUser.User_Name__c != null && currentUser.User_Name__c.length() > 0){
            selectedUsers.add(currentUser);
            usersMap.remove(profileUser);
          }                    
        }
      }            
    }

    system.debug('The current selected users are: ' + selectedUsers);
  }

  public void removeUser(){
    System.debug('user to be removed: ' + userToRemove);
    System.debug('current selected users: ' + selectedUsers.size());
    User__c userSelected;
    List<User__c> auxUsersList = new List<User__c>();
    Integer index = 0;
    if(!selectedUsers.isEmpty() && selectedUsers.size() > 0){
      for(User__c user : selectedUsers){
        userSelected = new User__c();
        System.debug('current user: ' + user);
        if(user.User_Name__c == userToRemove){                
          userSelected = user;
          System.debug('user to be removed: ' + userSelected + ' found at index: ' + index);
          selectedUsers.remove(index);
          break;
        }
        index++;
      }
      if(userSelected != null){
        usersMap.put(userSelected.User_Name__c, userSelected);
        auxUsersList = usersMap.values();
        fillUsersMap(auxUsersList);
      }
    }   
  }

  public PageReference save(){
    PageReference reference = null;

    System.debug('save() before the if, selected users: ' + selectedUsers);

    if(dataIsValid()){
      boolean rolesEnabled = false;
      boolean result = false;
      for(Role role : roles)
      {
        if(role.enableRole == true)
        {
          rolesEnabled = true;
        }
      }
      if(!rolesEnabled)
      {
        MessageManager.AddMessage(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'You must select at least one Role.');
        return reference; 
      }

      System.debug('save() before the  ABxUserProfileManager.setCreateBody(), selected users: ' + selectedUsers);

      if(!editMode){
        System.debug('Creating new user profile');
        ABxUserProfileManager.setCreateBody(userProfile, selectedUsers, roles);
        result = SaveData(userProfile);
      }
      else{
        System.debug('Updating the user profile');
        ABxUserProfileManager.setCreateBodyPut(userProfile, selectedUsers, roles);
        result = SaveDataItem(userProfile);
      }

      if(result)
      {
        System.debug('User Profile creado ' + result);
        String status = editMode ? 'Edited' : 'Created';
        ApexPages.Message msgAfterCreate = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'User Profile '+ status +' Successfully');
        ApexPages.addMessage(msgAfterCreate);
        reference = new pageReference(ABxGeneralConstant.userProfileList + '?' + ABxGeneralConstant.tabIdText + '=' + getTabId());
        clearAllDataLists();
      }
      else
      {
        System.debug('Error al crear User Profile ' + result);
        ApexPages.Message msgErrorCreate = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR ,'An error has occurred, please try again.');
        ApexPages.addMessage(msgErrorCreate);
      }
    }
    return reference;
  }
}
```

Now the explanation of the behavior of the class and my problem:

- The function `getUsers()` works well, there's any problem with it.
- The function `fillUsersMap()` seems to be working well, all the data is being filled inside the `Map<>`, don't worry about the data type of `users.User_Name__c` it is a `String`.
- At the function `setSelectedUsers()` I'm getting the value of `retrievedUsers` from the visualForce page, and that information is correct. The problem that I have is when I fill the `List<> selectedUsers`, sometimes it's being filled without problems and sometimes it doesn't work, same as the `Map<> usersMap`. The result is a empty `selectedUsers List<>` and a `usersMap Map<>` with the same data, there's no changes.
- But something that confuses me is the fact the I'm displaying the content of the `selectedUsers List<>` on my visualForce page and it's being displayed with no problems but with some `System.debug()` apparently that `List<>` is empty.
- Later when I try to remove data from the `selectedUsers` list calling to the function `removeUser()` all the data is deleted **the first time that I call that function**. On the second time that I fill the `selectedUsers` list and I try to remove a user again at `removeUser()` it works normally.
- Just for the record I can call the functions `setSelectedUsers()` and `removeUser()` from the visualForce page several times.
- And finally when I call the `save()` function, the `selectedUsers` list is empty all the data is erased.

Resuming: I'm not sure if I did the instance of the Lists properly, because the data of `selectedUsers` is being deleted when I call the `save()` function and so on with the `usersMap`

What's wrong here? Am I calling the instances of the `List<>` and `Map<>` in a wrong way?

Comment: Typically when you declare lists and maps in apex you follow them with the types of the entities they will be populated with. For example, in your case the initial declarations would be `public List<User__c> selectedUsers;` and `public Map<String, User__c> usersMap;` and you initialize them with the same type annotation. Have you tried setting the types explicitly?

Comment: Actually, with regards to my previous comment, this class won't even compile as you currently have it... You do need types on your list and map, and your class name is different than the constructor name.

Comment: It looks like you might have tried to extract sections of your code to help illustrate your problem, which is great, but as @Kyle says, there are a lot of reasons why the resulting code is invalid. It's hard to see what the issue might be without a clearer sense of the execution flow.

Comment: I'm having issues with the editor, it doesn't displays the code properly, I've checked the code structure and it's fine

Comment: Ok, I've already fixed the code @Kyle